# Cache implementation using cache framework

Tags: java, caching

I want to implement the cache in java.
Below is my requirement
I want to cache one table on server startup.Onece cached,I will fetch the data from cache like i will give key and it will return a value associated that key but suppose if key is not present than it will call a method and from that i can put the data in cache with that key and return me that value.
I googled and found google guava cache and to implement my requirement it is one option
but if possile than i want to know some other Cache frameworks so that i can choose option from that.
Please note that I am using JSP,Servelet JDBC means not using any spring,Hibernate or like that framework in my application.
Any help would be appriciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can read about these as you are using hibernate:
    EHCache (org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider)
    OSCache (org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider)
    SwarmCache (org.hibernate.cache.SwarmCacheProvider)
    JBoss TreeCache (org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider)

Comment: I am not using hibernate

Comment: Open Source:

Java Caching System (JCS)
OSCache
Java Object Cache (JOCache)
Java Caching Service, an open source implementation of the JCache API (SourceForge.net)
SwarmCache
JBossCache
IronEye Cache

Answer (score 0):

Find example of Java Caching System (JCS).I think it will solve your problem.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/UsingJCSBasicWeb.html

Comment: Thanks.It is useful.I will evaluate both options means Google Guava Cache and JCS cache

Comment: I evaluated Google Guava Cache.I want to go with this caching.but I want to know whether LoadingCache's get and it's load  method is thread safe or not.Any early help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only in memory cache then go for memcache/redis frameworks.
You can read more about them on their respective websites.